# Wrong scale for QWebEngineView with Windows Aero theme

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

We have problems with QWebEngineView on Windows 7 if an aero theme is enabled (default). Once the QWebEngineView is being rendered, the whole window is rendered in a wrong scale. When switching to a basic theme everything is being rendered as expected.

Simpe testcase I used:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://www.qt.io/"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In Chrome the page looks like:
[image]

But in the QWebEngineView the whole window is cut and uses the wrong scale:

[image]

Even worse: 
adding a QWebEngineView in a PyQt UI scales the whole UI window this way.

I checked the following environment variables:

```
AA_Use96Dpi=False
AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps=False
AA_UseDesktopOpenGL=False
AA_UseOpenGLES=False
AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL=False
AA_ShareOpenGLContexts=True
AA_EnableHighDpiScaling=False
AA_DisableHighDpiScaling=False
```

additionally I tried to set dpiaareness with values from 0-2 in qt.conf without any change.

Any hint / help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This is what I get: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ubhOKxY4PmwFL_c3doLXqEOTXvoo0onx/view?usp=sharing  , It would be interesting to indicate the version of PyQt5, QWebEngine has had problems with the drivers in the first versions of Qt 5.9 in Windows and Mac OS, I recommend you report the bug.

Comment: Thanks for testing! The effect ocours only in win7 aero theme and in any available / running pyqt5 version (5.10.0, 5.9.2). My versions:
    PyQt5==5.9.2
    Python 3.5.3

Comment: created https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68318

Comment: I recommend you update your version of PyQt to 5.10.1

Comment: same with pyqt 5.10.1

Comment: I recommend you check between the reports, that bug seems familiar to me and the solution I remember was to update the video driver, good luck.

Comment: Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 520
Current Mode: 1600 x 900 (32 bit) (60Hz)
Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (60.049Hz)
Driver Name: igdumdim64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igdumdim32,igd10iumd32,igd10iumd32
Driver Version: 21.20.16.4664

Answer (score 0):

It pointed out that updating to the very last intel video card driver solved the issue (unfortunately this version of the graphics driver is not stable / produces blue screens in other scenarios why we used the previous version so far). Thanks to @eyllanesc for the hint!

My conclusion is to switch to another framework asap as long QT depands on OpenGL (for embedding QtWebEngineView) - which has a very poor support on Windows and depands on the graphics card driver. We couldn't expect changes in near future to this concept in QT. Background can be found here: [Is there any way to use QtWebEngine without OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090346/is-there-any-way-to-use-qtwebengine-without-opengl)